# Draw iOS 7-style squircle programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, math, core-graphics, cgpath

I'm trying to find a way to draw a iOS 7-style icon 'squircle' shape programmatically, using core graphics. **I'm not asking how to draw a rounded rectangle**. A squircle is a superellipse:

[image: Squircle]

which is slightly different than a regular rounded rectangle:
[image: Rounded rectangle vs squircle]

[image: Music icon in squircle]

It's exact formula [is readily available](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx/60%7C%5E5%20%2b%20%7Cy/60%7C%5E5%20=%201). However, I can't figure out how to draw this using, for example, a CGPath, let alone fill it, and be able to resize it rather easily. All this while being entirely exact with the formula.

Comment: No I know how to make a rounded rectangle; I'm really a superellipsis of type squircle, as they use for springboard icons on iOS 7.

Comment: @RemyVanherweghem The `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` method was modified in iOS 7 to draw smoother corners. Also it doesn't seem to be a squircle: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/62341902567/unleashing-genetic-algorithms-on-the-ios-7-icon

Comment: (That said, the `UIBezierPath` methods don't produce a perfect match to the icon template, they're just closer than they were before.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in iOS **13**/ **Xcode 11** you can now use CALayerCornerCurve

Example

```
yourLayer.cornerCurve = CALayerCornerCurve.continuous
```

source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayercornercurve

Comment: Boom. This should be the accepted answer. This is how we do things in 2020 ya'll.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'CALayerCornerCurve' to type 'CGFloat'

Comment: the property name is `.cornerCurve` : 
`yourLayer.cornerCurve = CALayerCornerCurve.continuous`

Answer (score 17):

Quote from Wikipedia: [Superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)

> For n = 1/2, in particular, each of the four arcs is a **Quadratic Bézier curve** defined by the two axes; as a result, each arc is a segment of a parabola.

So why not try to approximate Squircle using Bezier curves? Both curves (Bezier  and Squircle) are defined by the parametric equations.

[UIBezierPath Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) have method: `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`

> Appends a cubic Bézier curve to the receiver’s path.

NOTE: Use of the `addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:` method gives worse results - tested.

I used this method and that's what happened as a result:

`red line` - rounded rectangle, `blue line` - rectangle from fours Bezier curves

[image: Rounded rectangle vs cubic Bezier curve]

If this result is interested - drawing code below.

NOTE: To achieve a more exact match Bezier curve can be required to change the coordinates of the four `corner points` (now they correspond to the angles of the rectangle in which is inscribed the figure).

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

//set rect size for draw
float rectSize = 275.;
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect) - rectSize/2, CGRectGetMidY(rect) - rectSize/2, rectSize, rectSize);

//Rounded rectangle
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
UIBezierPath* roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rectangle cornerRadius:rectSize/4.7];
[roundedPath stroke];

//Rectangle from Fours Bezier Curves
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
UIBezierPath *bezierCurvePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

//set coner points
CGPoint topLPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle));
CGPoint topRPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle));
CGPoint botLPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle));
CGPoint botRPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle));

//set start-end points
CGPoint midRPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle), CGRectGetMidY(rectangle));
CGPoint botMPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectangle), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle));
CGPoint topMPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectangle), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle));
CGPoint midLPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle), CGRectGetMidY(rectangle));

//Four Bezier Curve
[bezierCurvePath moveToPoint:midLPoint];
[bezierCurvePath addCurveToPoint:topMPoint controlPoint1:topLPoint controlPoint2:topLPoint];
[bezierCurvePath moveToPoint:midLPoint];
[bezierCurvePath addCurveToPoint:botMPoint controlPoint1:botLPoint controlPoint2:botLPoint];
[bezierCurvePath moveToPoint:midRPoint];
[bezierCurvePath addCurveToPoint:topMPoint controlPoint1:topRPoint controlPoint2:topRPoint];
[bezierCurvePath moveToPoint:midRPoint];
[bezierCurvePath addCurveToPoint:botMPoint controlPoint1:botRPoint controlPoint2:botRPoint];

[bezierCurvePath stroke];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 7):

A filled version of the accepted answer, also ported to Swift:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    context.saveGState()

    let rect = self.bounds
    let rectSize: CGFloat = rect.width
    let rectangle = CGRect(x: rect.midX - rectSize / 2, y: rect.midY - rectSize / 2, width: rectSize, height: rectSize)

    let topLPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.minX, y: rectangle.minY)
    let topRPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.maxX, y: rectangle.minY)
    let botLPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.minX, y: rectangle.maxY)
    let botRPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.maxX, y: rectangle.maxY)

    let midRPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.maxX, y: rectangle.midY)
    let botMPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.midX, y: rectangle.maxY)
    let topMPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.midX, y: rectangle.minY)
    let midLPoint = CGPoint(x: rectangle.minX, y: rectangle.midY)

    let bezierCurvePath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierCurvePath.move(to: midLPoint)
    bezierCurvePath.addCurve(to: topMPoint, controlPoint1: topLPoint, controlPoint2: topLPoint)
    bezierCurvePath.addCurve(to: midRPoint, controlPoint1: topRPoint, controlPoint2: topRPoint)
    bezierCurvePath.addCurve(to: botMPoint, controlPoint1: botRPoint, controlPoint2: botRPoint)
    bezierCurvePath.addCurve(to: midLPoint, controlPoint1: botLPoint, controlPoint2: botLPoint)

    context.setFillColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
    bezierCurvePath.fill()

    context.restoreGState()
}
```

perfect for use in a UIView subclass.

Answer (score 5):

Building on top of Ruslan's and Sunkas' answers above, I created a path that joins superelliptic "corners" with straight line segments; i.e. a **superelliptic analog** of the regular, rounded rectangle (like the mask seen around the edges of the iPhone X Simulator):

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    static func superellipse(in rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        // (Corner radius can't exceed half of the shorter side; correct if
        // necessary:)
        let minSide = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        let radius = min(cornerRadius, minSide/2)

        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)

        // The two points of the segment along the top side (clockwise):
        let p0 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.minY)
        let p1 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - radius, y: rect.minY)

        // The two points of the segment along the right side (clockwise):
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + radius)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - radius)

        // The two points of the segment along the bottom side (clockwise):
        let p4 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - radius, y: rect.maxY)
        let p5 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.maxY)

        // The two points of the segment along the left side (clockwise):
        let p6 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - radius)
        let p7 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + radius)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: p0)
        path.addLine(to: p1)
        path.addCurve(to: p2, controlPoint1: topRight, controlPoint2: topRight)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addCurve(to: p4, controlPoint1: bottomRight, controlPoint2: bottomRight)
        path.addLine(to: p5)
        path.addCurve(to: p6, controlPoint1: bottomLeft, controlPoint2: bottomLeft)
        path.addLine(to: p7)
        path.addCurve(to: p0, controlPoint1: topLeft, controlPoint2: topLeft)

        return path
    }
}
```

The points `p0` through `p7` in the code can be visualized in the following diagram:

[image]

If you pass a rectangle that is actually a *square*, and the corner radius is equal to or greater than half the side length, the straight line segments collapse (`p0` "merges" with `p1`, `p2` with `p3`, etc.) and you get the standard superellipse.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here don't look like the real thing. If you want something that actually matches the shape of an iOS icon then there's a detailed method [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles) with a lot of very magic numbers. Kudos to PaintCode for working it out.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a great answer since it doesn't get to the heart of what you're asking which is how to draw a superellipse** programmatically, but you can:

1. Download the SVG for the iOS7 icon shape here: http://dribbble.com/shots/1127699-iOS-7-icon-shape-PSD
2. Import it to your Xcode project
3. Add PocketSVG to your project: https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG
4. Load the SVG, and convert it to a UIBezierPath, from there you can scale and transform however you like:

   ```
   PocketSVG *myVectorDrawing = [[PocketSVG alloc] initFromSVGFileNamed:@"iOS_7_icon_shape"];

   UIBezierPath *myBezierPath = myVectorDrawing.bezier;

   // Apply your transforms here:
   [myBezierPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.5, 2.5)];
   [myBezierPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 50)];

   CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   myShapeLayer.path = myBezierPath.CGPath;
   myShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
   myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
   myShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

   [self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];
   ```

** It's maybe worth noting that the shape might not be an exact superellipse anyway: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMtN5.png

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Mark for the link and to PaintCode for figuring it out. It does indeed produce the same result as `CALayerCornerCurve.continuous` added in iOS 13. Here's Swift version of PaintCode's objc extension:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    /// Source: [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles)
    static func iOS7RoundedRect(in rect: CGRect, cornerRadius radius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
        let limit: CGFloat = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2 / 1.52866483
        let limitedRadius: CGFloat = min(radius, limit)
        
        func topLeft(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + x * limitedRadius, y: rect.origin.y + y * limitedRadius)
        }

        func topRight(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - x * limitedRadius, y: rect.origin.y + y * limitedRadius)
        }
            
        func bottomRight(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - x * limitedRadius, y: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - y * limitedRadius)
        }
            
        func bottomLeft(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + x * limitedRadius, y: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - y * limitedRadius)
        }
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        path.move(to: topLeft(1.52866483, 0.00000000))
        path.addLine(to: topRight(1.52866471, 0.00000000))
        path.addCurve(to: topRight(0.66993427, 0.06549600),
                      controlPoint1: topRight(1.08849323, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint2: topRight(0.86840689, 0.00000000))
        path.addLine(to: topRight(0.63149399, 0.07491100))
        path.addCurve(to: topRight(0.07491176, 0.63149399),
                      controlPoint1: topRight(0.37282392, 0.16905899),
                      controlPoint2: topRight(0.16906013, 0.37282401))
        path.addCurve(to: topRight(0.00000000, 1.52866483),
                      controlPoint1: topRight(0.00000000, 0.86840701),
                      controlPoint2: topRight(0.00000000, 1.08849299))
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight(0.00000000, 1.52866471))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomRight(0.06549569, 0.66993493),
                      controlPoint1: bottomRight(0.00000000, 1.08849323),
                      controlPoint2: bottomRight(0.00000000, 0.86840689))
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight(0.07491111, 0.63149399))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomRight(0.63149399, 0.07491111),
                      controlPoint1: bottomRight(0.16905883, 0.37282392),
                      controlPoint2: bottomRight(0.37282392, 0.16905883))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomRight(1.52866471, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint1: bottomRight(0.86840689, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint2: bottomRight(1.08849323, 0.00000000))
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft(1.52866483, 0.00000000))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomLeft(0.66993397, 0.06549569),
                      controlPoint1: bottomLeft(1.08849299, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint2: bottomLeft(0.86840701, 0.00000000))
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft(0.63149399, 0.07491111))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomLeft(0.07491100, 0.63149399),
                      controlPoint1: bottomLeft(0.37282401, 0.16905883),
                      controlPoint2: bottomLeft(0.16906001, 0.37282392))
        path.addCurve(to: bottomLeft(0.00000000, 1.52866471),
                      controlPoint1: bottomLeft(0.00000000, 0.86840689),
                      controlPoint2: bottomLeft(0.00000000, 1.08849323))
        path.addLine(to: topLeft(0.00000000, 1.52866483))
        path.addCurve(to: topLeft(0.06549600, 0.66993397),
                      controlPoint1: topLeft(0.00000000, 1.08849299),
                      controlPoint2: topLeft(0.00000000, 0.86840701))
        path.addLine(to: topLeft(0.07491100, 0.63149399))
        path.addCurve(to: topLeft(0.63149399, 0.07491100),
                      controlPoint1: topLeft(0.16906001, 0.37282401),
                      controlPoint2: topLeft(0.37282401, 0.16906001))
        path.addCurve(to: topLeft(1.52866483, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint1: topLeft(0.86840701, 0.00000000),
                      controlPoint2: topLeft(1.08849299, 0.00000000))
        
        path.close()
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed the parameter is slightly outdated when I compare `UIBezierPath`  generated cgPath on iOS 15 with the path this code generated. But the difference is very minimum.

Answer (score 1):

This would be pretty easy to do in OpenGL ES with a shader. Just draw a quad and pass in the x and y as vertex attributes. In the fragment shader, plug x and y into the equation. If the result <= 1, then the fragment is inside the shape. If I can get some free time I might try this and post it here.

If you want to use CGPath, I think the key is to parameterize x and y in terms of t, which goes from 0 to 2π. Then evaluate x and y at regular intervals. I'll try to figure this out in my free time, too, but my math is kind of rusty.

BTW, I'm certain that Apple is *not* using this formula. See the link that @millimoose posted: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/62341902567/unleashing-genetic-algorithms-on-the-ios-7-icon