# How to draw an iOS 7 style app icon?

Tags: ios, icons, ios7

Since the iOS 7 releases, the app icon has changed from **rounded rectangle** to **super-ellipse**.

[image: changes on the rounded corners]

My question is how to draw a super-ellipse in the most effective way? Is there any iOS library/project to implement super-ellipse drawing? Here is the [formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx/60%7C%5E5%20%2b%20%7Cy/60%7C%5E5%20=%201) mentioned by [Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18389114/482899).

[image: formula]

Comment: At WWDC, they said `-[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]` would yield the new shape in iOS7.

Comment: it's a superellipse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014105/drawing-a-superellipse-with-pure-css

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to draw a super-eclipse.

Draw your icon as a square and Apple will do that for you.

You can use this [website](http://makeappicon.com) to create all icons with the good size and good name for iOS 6, 7 and Android.

**EDIT :**

But, if you want to design your own icon for a button (for example) you can use [this template](http://dribbble.com/shots/1110930-iOS-7-Base-Roundrect-Shape-PSD) of .psd

Comment: Looks as if the site you mention only produces square icons (no rounded corners).

Comment: Only square icons because you don't need rounded icons for your App Icon.

Comment: I'm now producing my rounded icons (for use on a web site) the same way Apple apparently does: by rounding a square form using CSS. So yes, there is sometimes need for rounded icons, but one can get them in perhaps sufficient quality without special tools.