# Drawing a superellipse with pure CSS

Tags: css

As the title says: How do you draw a superellipse (specifically, the Apple iOS7 / 8 one) with pure CSS? Not quite sure if it's possible, but still.

Reference image:
[image]

Comment: How should it look? Provide an image.

Comment: @Flopet17 Reference article: http://www.pixelresort.com/blog/start-making-ios-7-icons-with-the-app-icon-template-3-0/

Basically, it's the one Apple uses in iOS 7 / 8.

Comment: Unless you use SVG or HTML canvas, the best that you can do is draw a square with rounded corners.  Anything else will take a lot of work.

Comment: @MarcAudet I guess that's my only option for now. Will look into using SVG.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find the equation?

Comment: @MarcAudet I just googled iOS8 app icon :)

Comment: For what it is worth, there is a whole genre of these curves! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Answer (score 11):

This isn't exact, but you may be able to tweak the idea to get something acceptable to you.  Basically, you layer `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements with elliptical borders under the containing element with circular borders to get the effect.

I set the background color of the pseudo elements to blue and green for visualization, but they would be set to the color of the containing element.

Hover the element in the snippet to see combined sections.

```css
div {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    border-radius:20%/20%;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:relative;
}

div::before, div::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

div::before {
    border-radius: 2%/30%;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: -2px;
    left: -2px;
}

div::after {
    border-radius: 30%/2%;
    background-color: green;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    top: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
}

div:hover,
div:hover::before,
div:hover::after {
    background-color:#ff4949
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image: Red and blue pseudo-elements for visualization of technique]

Answer (score 3):

We can use an SVG as mask to create a superellipse. I think the best solution for now.

```css
.superellipse {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  --mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='200' height='200' viewBox='0 0 200 200' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M199.178 99.589C199.178 165.982 165.982 199.179 99.5893 199.179C33.1963 199.179 0 165.982 0 99.589C0 33.1964 33.1963 0 99.5893 0C165.982 0 199.178 33.1964 199.178 99.589Z' fill='black'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 / 100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, orangered);
  
  /* to center the text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="superellipse"></div>
```

The svg that I use:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M199.178 99.589C199.178 165.982 165.982 199.179 99.5893 199.179C33.1963 199.179 0 165.982 0 99.589C0 33.1964 33.1963 0 99.5893 0C165.982 0 199.178 33.1964 199.178 99.589Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

I encoded it with [url-encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)

### What about CSS Houdini?

Now we can use [CSS Paint API](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-paint-api-1/) that provided by [CSS Houdini](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Houdini). We'll use a library called [smooth-corners](https://github.com/wopian/smooth-corners), that registers a new paint which is drawing a superellipse.

But only Chrome and Edge are [supported](https://caniuse.com/css-paint-api) for now.

```js
if (CSS && 'paintWorklet' in CSS) CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('https://unpkg.com/smooth-corners')
```

```css
.superellipse {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  mask-image: paint(smooth-corners);
  -webkit-mask-image: paint(smooth-corners);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, deeppink, orangered);
}
```

```html
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 0.6"></div>
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 1.5"></div>
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 2.2"></div>
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 2.6"></div>
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 3"></div>
<div class="superellipse" style="--smooth-corners: 4"></div>
```

[image]