# Create a rounded inflated square

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please help me!!! How create a rounded inflated square UIImageView. I need to create icons as a contact such as in the viber application .
Sample image

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35579/create-a-rounded-inflated-square-in-illustrator-photoshop

I Asked about rounded INFLATED square, And i think questions have a different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do it is to use a mask and apply it to your image.

```
 - (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

See this tutorial : http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html#comment-47347

And the stackoverflow topic about your issue:
[How to Mask an UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview)

Comment: Which begs the question: How do you create a rounded inflated square mask.

Comment: jregnauld, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate here: [Draw iOS 7-style squircle programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389114/draw-ios-7-style-squircle-programatically)

Anyway, what you want is a squircle/superellipse. Read up on the uibezierpath and customize the curves bigger for your usage.